# CoordinatorLayout shifts Toolbar back after fast scroll

Tags: android, parallax, android-coordinatorlayout

I try to create a parallax effect for Toolbar. Downloaded many examples like https://github.com/anton46/WhatsApp-ProfileCollapsingToolbar, https://github.com/k0shk0sh/CoordinatorLayoutExample, https://github.com/hanscappelle/CoordinatorBehaviorExample, https://github.com/henrytao-me/smooth-app-bar-layout, https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare (you can see images in these packages).

Everything works right in some devices, but for HTC (Android 4.4) it works badly. When I try to scroll (swipe) a Toolbar fast down or up, a Toobar scrolls, but then instantly returns to initial position.

It is amazing that this bug exists even in Play Market on this phone.

How can I fix this behaviour?

Comment: provide code here!!

Comment: @Sjd, sorry, every project above contains code and contains this bug.

Comment: I think, this is a bug of a certain device model. It was reproduced in many applications.